# String Replacement with Wildcard

Tags: regex, bash, unix

Say I would like to delete all strings that follow a wild-card pattern such as '-*'

Example:  Given this list

```
149959
357518
357518-w2
441492
441492-w2 
441492-w3
```

How do I delete every pattern occurrence beginning with '-' to achieve the following:

```
149959
357518
357518
441492
441492
441492
```

I've tried various pattern matching schemes but they don't give me the required result:

```
echo "${list//-w*/}"
```

Returns:

```
149959
357518
357518
```

Any help would be appreciated! Hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

For file:

```
% grep -o '^[^-]\+' file.txt
149959
357518
357518
441492
441492
441492
```

For variable you can use Here Strings:

```
% grep -o '^[^-]\+' <<<"$list"
149959
357518
357518
441492
441492
441492
```

Comment: Woah! Super cool, thank you so much for the pointers.  Would have taken me forever looking through a unix manual before I could have figured this out.

Comment: @seldamat Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`:

```
echo $list | sed 's/-\w*//g'
```

or

```
sed 's/-\w*//g' <<< "$list"
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj It'd lastly depend on what input the OP has. I'll add your suggestion as well =)

Comment: Thanks for the hint using sed, which I've been avoiding until I get grep or awk down first.  Archived for the future ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Using bash string manipulation and a `for` loop:

`for i in $(cat my.lst); do echo ${i%%-*};done`

Edit: Same solution with pipe:

`while read i; do echo ${i%%-*};done < my.lst`

Comment: ah pretty nifty solution as well, good ol' for loops ^_^ -- however for my purposes I would like to pipe the result so grep seems to win this time (unless there is a way to pipe a for loop?)

Comment: ah very nice, haven't seen an example of usage like that before! thanks for the info